# Is this called "a checkpoint"?

Tags: phrase-request, image-identification

Could someone tell me what the picture shows? I tried with *checkpoint*, but I couldn't find further information.

> [image: a glass cabin, a separate gate for pedestrians and one for vehicles]

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? The entirety of the picture could certainly be called a *checkpoint*. Why do you think that's wrong?  What specific component and function are you thinking of?

Comment: It might help if you told us what the text on the booth and above the pedestrian entrance says.

Comment: Could it be just called "an entrance control post"? A rather small gate-keeper's booth and a slot for electronic cards the  turnstile is equipped with tells me it's not a checkpoint per se.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't quite clear from the picture what it is, and that is relevant because it depends on the purpose of the structure. For example, it could be a tollbooth on a motorway, or it could be a security checkpoint at a border. These type of barriers are used in various ways. *Checkpoint* implies that some kind of procedure is involved, for example showing an identity card. This wouldn't be the case with a tollbooth where a simple exchange of money happens. In other words, a checkpoint is a place where something is checked, usually that the person has the permission to cross through the barriers.

Comment: Except a motorway tollbooth is unlikely to have a side gate for pedstrians.

Comment: True, but the point remains that without context it is unclear what these barriers are functioning as.